# Meteor/Mongodb find related records based on document's tags

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm quite new to Meteor and its Mongo DB, and I'm wondering how I could find 'related documents'.

I have a collection of posts, that has tags, like this:

```
[{ title : 'title', tags: [{name : 'tag1'}, {name : 'tag2'}]}]
```

Now I want to query my database, to find posts that have an intersection on these tag set, where I want to order the results by size of the intersection descending.

How should this be encoded into a find() query, where the query is given an array of tags to check against as input?

Answer (score 1):

You can also find simply as:

```
Collection.find({"tags.name" : "tag1"})
```

This will give all matching documents that have `'tag1'` in the `tags` array.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with this structure:

```
[{
    title: 'title',
    tags: ['tag1', 'tag2'],
}]
```

Then you use:

```
Documents.find({
    tags: {$all: [ "alpha", "beta", "gamma" ]}
});
```

See here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/#op._S_all

Now, it may or may not work with complex objects as you have, I'm not sure. Try this:

```
Documents.find({
    tags: {$all: [{name: "alpha"}, {name: "beta"}]}
});
```

If you need the specified structure and the above query does not work, you're left with the `$where` query. It is very flexible, but not recommended as it's much slower than the others. See here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/#op._S_where

---

**EDIT:** this one should do the job:

```
Documents.find({
    'tags.name': {$all: ["alpha", "beta"]}
});
```

Comment: is there a comparable thing to $all, that doesn't mean ALL but INTERSECT? so it matches if it intersects with tags.name, ie. some tags match. would be better if we can then sort it on the size of the intersection

Comment: how do you exclude the current document? like a "related posts" in a sidebar of a blog post.